# I am not able to update my records in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am simply updating my records in a database. I am passing Id and status to the controller and want to update to database but I am not able to do it.
Controller name is Examtest, model name is crud_model, view name is categories.
This code is of View:

```
foreach ($user_data as $key => $val) {
                                          $status = $val['status'];
                                               if ($status == "Active") {
                                               $st = '<p class="text-success">ACTIVE</p>';
                                               $stl = '<a href="examtest/update_status?id='.$val['category_id'].'?sta='.$val['status'].'">Make Inactive</a>';
                                               }else{
                                               $st = '<p class="text-danger">INACTIVE</p>'; 
                                               $stl = '<a href="examtest/update_status?id='.$val['category_id'].'?sta='.$val['status'].'">Make Active</a>';                                             
                                               }
```

This code is of Controller, I have created one function :

```
public function update_status()
    {
         $this->load->model('crud_model');
        $data['user_data']=$this->crud_model->update_status();
        if (isset($_REQUEST['sta'])) {


        if ($data=="Active") {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"Successfully");
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_clas','alert-success');
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"Not Successfully");
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_clas','alert-danger');
        }


        }
        return $this->load->view('backend/teacher/categories');
    }
```

This code is of model, I had created one function :

```
function update_status(){
   $this->load->database();
  $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
  $saval=$_REQUEST['sta'];
  if ($saval="Active") {
    $status= "Inactive";
  }
  else 
  {
    $status = "Active";
  }

  $data=array('status'=>$status);
  $this->db->where('category_id',$id);
  return $this->db->update('tbl_categories',$data);

}
```

Where am I going wrong? I had just created some record in that I had given Action button, if someone click on select option it will show them a select option if someone choose first option it will update my records in database too.

Answer (score 0):

Please use last_query() method, to print current update query.

To print last query please use -

```
echo $this->db->last_query();die;
```

**Update query --**

```
$data=array('status'=>$status);
$this->db->where('category_id',$id);
$this->db->update('tbl_categories',$data);
echo $this->db->last_query();die;
return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

Please try this.

Comment: also it is not ubdating on db too

Comment: have you printed the last query? and please copy the last query and execute manually into phpmyadmin.